# Can't open shortcut Intent using "Suggest shortcuts In-App Promo SDK"

Tags: android, app-actions

I followed all steps from https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/in-app-promo-sdk and it still isn't working does anyone know why this isn't working for me?

The error message is

> com.google.assistant.appactions.suggestions.client.ClientException: Failed to verify the APK signature. If this is a development build, please make sure to update the preview of your app in the App Actions Test Tool.

Here is the code for open ShortcutSuggestion Intent.

```
val orderShortcut = AppShortcutSuggestion.builder()
                        .setAppShortcutIntent(appShortcutIntent)
                        .setCommand("order my bubble tea")
                        .build()

                shortcutsClient.createShortcutSuggestionIntent(orderShortcut)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { intent ->
                        application.startActivity(
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        );
                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        Log.e("Log", "Failed to get shortcut settings intent", it);
                    }
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/legacy/test-tool , have you followed these steps? You need to do them if you're testing this

Comment: yes, followed all steps.

Comment: This error message is discussed in the in-app promo documentation. If you didn't publish your app to the Play store, you need to be working with an App Actions preview. https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/in-app-promo-sdk#failed_to_verify_the_apk_signature

Comment: If you have steps to reproduce this, you should put them into the question, not just a link to the documentation.  Anyone should be able to reproduce by following your instructions as stated here.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. The Shortcut creation activity shows for a moment and disappears.
I have raised a bug on Android Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201790858

Comment: @Neernay please any update about the issue?

Comment: @Neernay the solution is you have to use capabilities that are available in the shortcuts.xml file